# Hyperlinking attribute in ArcGIS standalone tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, relates, hyperlink

I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 and have created a 1:m relationship in a File GDB. The 1:m relationship joins a table containing a URL to a point geometry. Some points have more than one file hence the 1:m join. After successfully creating the relationship, I wanted to use the field in the table to open the Image. It seems however, that ArcGIS stand-alone tables cannot use hyperlinks.

Is there a workaround to this or can ArcGIS not use hyperlinks in stand-alone tables?

Comment: Please explain properly formatting a link field in the above? I've created my relationship class (1:M) in a stand alone table and my feature class. However the identify tool populates with text and no option to click on a link.

Comment: There are multiple threads about this topic over on [geonet](https://community.esri.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&q=hyperlink%20in%20related%20table%20arcmap) and it appears to me to be a limitation in ArcMap. My only suggestion is you add a new field to your related table which includes a full path version to your pdf files. I often have 3 fields: a path to a folder, the file name and the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the Hyperlink tool with a field in a stand alone table, but once you create the relationship between the table and your feature class the results of the Identify tool will recognize link like text in the fields of your related table(s), they just have to be properly formatted.

I have just this same issue and it works for me with a field populated by paths to PDF files, Identify recognized it as a "hyperlinkable" field even though the text was not a UNC path, it was Z:\path\file.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

You use the Identify tool to see the 1:M relationship and then you can use the hyperlink.

[image: 1:M relationship and hyperlinking]

In this example I have a point dataset called *testp* which has a relationship with a table called *ttp* and in this standalone table is a field called HYPERLINK.